# How can principal components be correlated when averaged?

Tags: pca, mean, independence

I am working with sequences that consist of 20 building blocks. Those 20 building blocks were characterized using different parameters and after linear PCA, the first 3 principal components were extracted. Now, what I am interested in is characterizing groups of sequences using these three PCs. For that, I first average the values for each PC over a sequence and next, I average those values over each group. Now, when I make a correlation matrix of the final averages, I find those 3 PCs to be highly correlated (r > 0.9). I am a bit confused on how this is possible starting from three PCs that are by definition orthogonal to each other?

Comment: Consider a simple case of two groups.  Suppose one group consists of all observations with a negative loading on the first PC and the other group consists of all observations with a positive loading.  What happens when you average over the groups?

Comment: Then you would have two final datapoints, one with a positive and one with a negative value for PC1. @whuber

Comment: Right: and what would that imply about correlations among the averages of the PCs?

Comment: I am afraid I don’t understand what you are alluding to @whuber